# How do I specify domain in d3.scale.ordinal() ?

Tags: javascript, visualization, d3.js

```
var W = 100;
var H = 200;

var data = [{v:4}, {v:8}, {v:15}, {v:16}, {v:23}, {v:42}];

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, max_x]).range([0, W]);
var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).rangeBands([0, H]);
```

How do I automatically enumerate the domain of data without typing it out e.g., 0, 1, 2, 3
I have tried `domain(data)`, and `domain([0, data.length])`, but I need all the values in between.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the domain of the ordinal scale to be the indexes of your data, then use [d3.range](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_range). For example, `d3.range(data.length)` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.