# How to make ordinal tick labels adjust automatically in D3

Tags: d3.js

As you can see in the example, the tick labels on an ordinal axis (scale) become crowded and illegible as the domain grows. How can I make them adjust automatically as they would on a linear axis?

(I suppose I could use a linear scale instead, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284453/how-do-i-specify-domain-in-d3-scale-ordinal) and the answer from Mike Bostock himself suggest that the ordinal scale is more appropriate for this type of data. After all, the domain is discrete and I'm making a modified bar chart, where a convenient padding setting is useful.)

```js
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(1,6))
  .range([0,200]);

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(1,51))
  .range([0,200]);

var xLinear = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1,50])
  .range([0,200]);

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,10)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,50)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,100)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xLinear));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width='300' height='150'></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution takes advantage of the very smart built-in function `d3.ticks()`, which deals with edge cases so we don't have to.

```js
var dataSmall = d3.range(1,8),
    dataLarge = d3.range(1, 51);

var xS = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(dataSmall)
  .rangeRound([0,200]);

var xL = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(dataLarge)
  .rangeRound([0,200]);

function makeAxis(scale) {
  var n=5, 
      data = scale.domain(),
      dataLength = data.length;
  
  return d3.axisBottom(scale).tickValues( 
    dataLength > n ? d3.ticks(data[0], data[dataLength-1], n) : data);
}

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,10)')
  .call(makeAxis(xS));

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,50)')
  .call(makeAxis(xL));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width='300' height='150'></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter ticks manually then, like here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3212294 (this is D3 v3, please see the v4 version below)

```js
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(1,6))
  .range([0,200]);

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(1,51))
  .range([0,200]);

var tickValues = x
   .domain()
   .filter(function(d, i) { return !((i + 1) % Math.floor(x.domain().length / 10)); });
           
var xLinear = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1,50])
  .range([0,200]);

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,10)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,50)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickValues(tickValues));

d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,100)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xLinear));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width='300' height='150'></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I found a more robust implementation that is also easier.

Comment: Linear scale? Could you perhaps share your solution, at least the idea? It is always interesting, how to solve something which is not natively built into the tool.

Comment: No, ordinal scale. My answer is posted.